# SQL query to retrive data from a single table based on two specific date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

I'm trying to retrieve the data where in for each id, the query should check if another id are falling under date1 and date2 and get the qty and id of those.

The out put should look like..

[image]

Comment: Why isn't ind-1/ind-5 in the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self join of the table:

```
select t1.id, t2.id as temp, t2.qty
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on (t1.id <> t2.id) and (t2.date1 between t1.date1 and t1.date2) and (t2.date2 between t1.date1 and t1.date2)
```